# How to control where NPM finds server.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I'm following [this blog](https://medium.com/@dabit3/introduction-to-using-npm-as-a-build-tool-b41076f488b0#.lw3myhdza) and in the section 4, they show how to execute and run an application. It's working as described.

Now, I'd like to put the file *server.js*, which is the entry point in a directory called *app*. The command *npm start* doesn't find it any more, though.

After some googling I've read that I'm supposed to put in the following line in the *package.json*, which I did.

> "start": "app/server.js",

The problem is that it still can't find it and I can't really diagnose the issue. Is it because the entry point **must** be in the root? Does the *start* element need to be placed in a certain order in JSON file? Am I specifying the path incorrectly (I've tried "\" and "/" etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the call to node:

```
"start": "node app/server.js",
```

Also make sure to place the above line in the `"scripts"` section of `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app/server.js",
  ...
},
```

Comment: I'm sure this is **one** of the issues, hehe. Now, that it's corrected, I get error *missing script: start*. What else might it be? Or is it a matter for a new question?

Comment: One thing it could be is that `"start: "node app/server.js""` is not in the `"scripts"` portion of your `"package.json"`.

Comment: Stupid *scripts* section... Stupid *start* element... Stupid *NodeJs*... (indistinguishable mumbling...)    Awesome! That did the trick. I'm noob at this so it's almost funny. Almost.  :)

Comment: No problem mate, we've all been there, happy to help out :)

Comment: I took the liberty to embed the comments into the answer to make it from great to perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `scripts.start` in you `package.json` is specified as the command that will run whenever you execute `npm start`.  This means that whatever value you put in there will be run directly as an executable, so it's not just a matter of specifying a path.

You have two options now to fix your issue:

- Specify a full command: `node app/server.js`.
- Make `app/server.js` executable: Set its executable bit (`chmod +x app/server.js`) and add a hashbang line to the file (`#!/usr/bin/env node` as the first line of the file)

Answer (score 0):

The 'start' key in scripts section of `package.json`, describes the script to be run by npm when 'npm start' is executed.

```
...

"scripts": {
    "start": "node app/server.js"
}

...
```

However, some servers may choose to start the application in other possible manners. It makes sense to also define a `main` file as the starting point of your application. This can be done as follows:

```
...

"main": "app/server.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app/server.js"
}

...
```

Comment: I thought that *main* was supposed to point to the *index.js* of the starting page. But perhaps that's a simplification that I'm tricked by?

Comment: Its the starting point of application. Basically the file which has to be executed by node to start the application. It can be called anything, including index.js. If the "main" key is missing, node looks for a index.js file by default in current working directory to execute.

Comment: Very helpful. So, I could have **any** element in the JSON file? E.g. it would work with *"donkey":"node bazinga/shazoo.js"* if I execute *npm donkey*?

Comment: No. In that manner 'start' is special. If you had `"donkey":"node bazinga/shazoo.js" `in package.json scripts section, you would execute it as `npm run donkey`.